# "mid" without a following hyphen in these words?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation, writing-style, hyphenation

The Chicago Manual, 16th edition, says that "mid" is followed by a hyphen only if a capitalized word (mid-Atlantic) or a number (mid-1950s) follows. That said, I believe that all of the following examples would be correct without any hyphens (based on Chicago's ruling), agreed? midsummer, midfall, midautumn, midwinter, midspring, midparagraph, midpurgatory, midsentence, midmorning, midafternoon, midevening.

Comment: According to the *Chicago Manual of Style*, yes. But according to the predominant American usage, [no](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=middecade%2Cmid-decade%2C+midautumn%2C+mid-autumn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmiddecade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmid%20-%20decade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmidautumn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmid%20-%20autumn%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor: Note that when you try to run an Ngram/Google Books search for "mid-decade" and "mid-autumn," the tool warns you "Replaced **mid-decade** with **mid - decade** to match how we processed the books. Replaced **mid-autumn** with **mid - autumn** to match how we processed the books." I don't know what it's doing when it makes those replacements, but it certainly doesn't provide any examples of the results for "mid - decade" and "mid - autumn" in the "Search in Google Books" fields beneath the Ngram graph.

Comment: Speaking from a UK perspective I would lean towards retaining the hyphen in all of those.

Comment: @WS2 *Midsomer* [Midsummer] *Murders*? No hyphen.

Comment: @DavidHandelman I think *midsummer* is one that I would make an exception of. Don't know why but I just would. I would certainly not write *midautumn* or *midspring* - possibly *midwinter*. It seems to be that *midsummer* and *midwinter* have the status of complete words in their own right, which the others don't - possibly due to frequency of use. And that is exactly what my spellchecker thinks. It puts red lines under *midspring* and *midautumn* but not under either *midsummer* or *midwinter*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's effectively asking us to adjudicate between different style guides

Comment: ... and after 'That said', one expects some suggestion contrary to CMoS's recommendations. FWIW, I'd hyphenate one or two of the words proffered (and avoid using one or two).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several U.S. style guides recommend a treatment of the prefix *mid-* that closely resembles the one in *Chicago*. For example, from *The Associated Press Stylebook and Briefing on Media Law* (2002):

> **mid-** No hyphen unless a capitalized word follows: mid-America, mid-Atlantic, midsummer, midterm

From *The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage* (1999):

> **mid(-).** Except before a proper name or a number, compounds formed with mid are one word: midafternoon, midair, mid-America, mid-Atlantic, midchannel, midcontinent, midday, Mideast, midfield, midland, midlife, midmorning, midnight, midpoint, midocean [out of alphabetical order, I notice], midsection, midship, midsize, midstream, midsummer, Midtown (Manhattan's), midtown, midway, midweek, Midwest, midwife
>
> Also, mid-1960, mid-1960's, mid-'60, mid-60's, mid-ninth century, mid-16th century.

From *The St. Martin's Handbook*, fifth edition (2003):

> **57c Using hyphens with prefixes and suffixes**
>
> Most words containing prefixes or suffixes are written without hyphens: *antiwar*, *gorillalike*. Only in the following cases do you need a hyphen:
>
> **WITH CAPITALIZED BASE WORDS** [Examples:} pro-Bush, un-American, non-Catholic
>
> **WITH FIGURES** [Examples:] pre-1960, post-1945
>
> **WITH CERTAIN PREFIXES AND SUFFIXES** [Examples:] all-state, self-possessed, quasi-legislative, mayor-elect, fifty-odd
>
> Hyphens are also used with *ex-* and *-some* when these mean "former" and "approximately," respectively: *ex-husband*, *twenty-some*
>
> **WITH COMPOUND BASE WORDS** [Examples:] pre-high school, pro-civil rights, post-cold war
>
> **FOR CLARITY OR EASE OF READING** [Examples:] re-cover, anti-inflation, troll-like

And from *MLA Style Manual*, second edition (1998):

> **3.4.6 Hyphens**
>
> ...
>
> h. In general do not use hyphens after prefixes (e.g., *anti-*, *co-*, *multi-*, *non-*, *over-*, *post-*, *pre-*, *re-*, *semi-*, *sub-*, *un-*, *under-*). [Examples omitted.] But sometimes a hyphen is called for after a prefix.
>
> [Example:] post-Victorian (Use a hyphen before a capital letter.)
>
> [Example:] re-cover (The hyphen distinguishes this verb meaning "cover again," from *recover*, meaning "get back.")
>
> [Example:] anti-icing (Without the hyphen, the doubled vowel would make the term hard to recognize.)

To judge from *The Oxford Guide to Style* (2003), however, preferences in the UK lean much more toward retaining hyphens with at least some prefixes. That guide has a special subsection on *mid-*:

> **5.10.2 Prefixes and combining forms**
>
> ...
>
> The prefix *mid-* is now considered to be an adjective in its own right in such combinations as *mid shot*, *mid grey*, *mid range*, and *mid nineteenth century*, though as a combining form it retains its hyphen in *mid-air*, *mid-engined*, *mid-Victorian*, and other forms.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with these answers; however, I'd like to add "mid back" since I'm in the medical field.  This never has a hyphen and is never one word.  I get this question all the time. I'm an orthopedic medical transcriptionist of 25+ years.  Thanks!